# WordPress: Dynamically use the Category of the current Custom Post Type to a new WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm inside a Custom Post Type template and I want to make a new WP_Query to display a different Custom Post Type post using the same category of the current one. I know I can just put it as a string but I need to make it dynamic for my CPT template.

For example:

```
<?php
  $args = array (
         'post_type' => 'new_cpt_to_display',
         'category_name' => 'category_of_the_current_cpt' );

  $new_cpt_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

I hope I explained it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Got an idea from the previous answer.

```
<?php
  $cat = get_the_category();
  $cat_name = esc_html( $cat[0]->name );
  $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'new_cpt_to_display',
    'category_name' => $cat_name
  );

  $new_cpt_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) which returns an array of category IDs for the current post and the `category__in` (results for each of the categories) or `category__and` (results in all the categories) arguments for `WP_Query`.

```
$category_ids = get_the_category();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'new_cpt_to_display',
    'category__in' => $category_ids
);

$new_cpt_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @doublesharp, but unfortunately, I already tried `get_the_category()` with my sample code and got an error of _Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array...._ With your sample using `category__in()`, I got _Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string_ I also tried `echo get_the_category();` to see if it catches the category of the current custom post but it only displays the word _Array_.

Comment: The function returns an array of IDs, not a string, which is why you are getting that error. WP_Query will take an array as an argument, but not if you pass it in as a querystring - you have to pass an `$arg` array to `WP_Query` as in the example. If this isn't working, post the full code you are using (since what is in my answer will work fine).

Comment: I really appreciate your help @doublesharp. It does work but when I tried using it in a `while` loop, it displays all the posts in `new_cpt_to_display` custom post type, it's not using the specific category the current post has. Your answer was so useful, I just had to modify it a bit. I used `esc_html( $cat[0]->name );` to return a string and used it to `category_name`. It's now displaying correctly. Thank you so much! I have another problem that's giving me headaches for more than a week, if you want to look at it - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33622038/5522358